# MySQL select with CONCAT condition

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements, where-clause, concatenation

I'm trying to compile this in my mind.. i have a table with firstname and lastname fields
and i have a string like "Bob Jones" or "Bob Michael Jones" and several others.

the thing is, i have for example
Bob in firstname, and
Michael Jones in lastname

so i'm trying to

```
SELECT neededfield, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as firstlast 
  FROM users 
 WHERE firstlast = "Bob Michael Jones"
```

but it says unknown column "firstlast".. can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

The aliases you give are for the output of the query - they are not available within the query itself.

You can either repeat the expression:

```
SELECT neededfield, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as firstlast 
FROM users
WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) = "Bob Michael Jones"
```

or wrap the query

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT neededfield, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as firstlast 
  FROM users) base 
WHERE firstLast = "Bob Michael Jones"
```

Comment: this was to set as answer.

Comment: after a while, i can say that i agree to use this as a better answer

Comment: @Alex you can select a different answer if you wish to do so

Comment: For a bulky table with many rows, I think it would be unwise to use the "wrap the query" version.

Answer (score 34):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM  (
        SELECT neededfield, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as firstlast 
        FROM users 
    ) a
WHERE firstlast = "Bob Michael Jones"
```

Comment: works perfect for me, thanks a lot :) and thanks for putting text in code, i forgot

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT needefield, CONCAT(firstname, ' ',lastname) as firstlast 
FROM users 
WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) = "Bob Michael Jones"
```

Answer (score 8):

Use CONCAT_WS().

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',firstname,lastname) as firstlast FROM users 
WHERE firstlast = "Bob Michael Jones";
```

The first argument is the separator for the rest of the arguments.

Comment: so then it should be `CONCAT_WS(' ', ..`

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
SELECT neededfield, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as firstlast 
  FROM users 
WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) = "Bob Michael Jones"
```

Your alias firstlast is not available in the where clause of the query unless you do the query as a sub-select.

Answer (score 7):

There is an alternative to repeating the `CONCAT` expression or using subqueries. You can make use of the `HAVING` clause, which recognizes column aliases.

```
SELECT 
  neededfield, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS firstlast 
FROM
  users 
HAVING firstlast = "Bob Michael Jones"
```

Here is a working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9601/1).

Comment: Not sure why the having clause is not garnering more attention.  It allows the direct use of the virtual column name.  Does the having clause have more overhead?

Comment: @Paul having clause applied in the end of executing query so we can use it to set condition on aggregate functions(like MAX()). Having clause cannot use index so it is slow.