# Concat in Codeigniter Active Record

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I am trying a Concat for an autocomplete, Using CI's Active Record.

My Query is :

```
$this->db->select("CONCAT(user_firstname, '.', user_surname) AS name", FALSE);
$this->db->select('user_id, user_telephone, user_email');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('name', $term);
```

I keep getting an MySQL Error from this saying:

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause'

Which is true, However I have just created in my Concat clause. I ideally need $term to match the Concatenated firstname and surname fields.

Any ideas what I can do to improve this? I am considering just writing this as an flat MySQL Query..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('user_id, user_telephone, user_email, CONCAT(user_firstname, '.', user_surname) AS name', FALSE);
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('name', $term);
```

Not sure why you are running multiple selects. So just put it as a single select. It's probably that the 2nd one is overriding the first one and thus overwriting the concatenation to create the `name` column.

Comment: Thanks Cryptic. I have found myself an alternate solution, In the where clause I concatenated like so : $this->db->where("CONCAT(user_firstname, '.', user_surname) LIKE '%".$term."%'", NULL, FALSE);

Comment: that was epic solution, would you mind to explain it?

Answer (score 11):

```
$this->db->select("CONCAT((first_name),(' '),(middle_name),(' '),(last_name)) as candidate_full_name");
```

Try like above 100% it will work in ci.

Comment: Only this works for me in CI 3. In CI 2, parenthesis was not a problem.

Comment: This is the actually Answer to concat two fields in CI, fields must be not null

Answer (score 4):

If cryptic solution doen't work then try it.

```
$query = "SELECT * 
  FROM  (
        SELECT user_id, user_telephone, user_email, CONCAT(user_firstname, ' ', user_surname) name
        FROM users 
    ) a
WHERE name LIKE '%".$term."%'";
$this->db->query($query);
```

Source: [MySQL select with CONCAT condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734570/mysql-select-with-concat-condition)

Answer (score 4):

You have to SELECT the fields that you want concat like so:

```
$this->db->select('user_id, user_telephone, user_email, user_firstname, user_surname, CONCAT(user_firstname, '.', user_surname) AS name', FALSE);
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('name', $term);
```

Answer (score 4):

This will also solve the issue:

```
$this->db->select('user_id, user_telephone, user_email, user_firstname, user_surname, CONCAT(user_firstname,user_surname) AS name', FALSE);
$this->db->from('users');
```