# MySQL Drop table doesn't work for prefix

Tags: mysql, sql-drop

I am trying to drop tables with wp_ prefix but its giving error below

`Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE TABLE LIKE 'wp_%'' at line 1`

Here is my query

```
"DROP TABLE WHERE TABLE LIKE '{$wp}%'"
```

What is wrong in this query? Please help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't selectively `delete` tables. You have to specifically `delete` each table, since deletion can't use a filter. You could probably use the metadata to get the names of all of your tables, and then find out in your code which ones start with `wp_`. Then, you would just loop through your list of tables to delete and then delete them with `drop table [table-name];`.

To get the list of table names from metadata, use `select table_name from information_schema.tables;`.

Comment: okay so information_schema.tables will only check in current database?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, yes. If you want to change the database you're looking at, then use `use [database-name];`.

Comment: No no, I just want to do in current database.

Comment: I have tried this code but it's not deleting tables but only showing.`SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE ',table_name,';')
                FROM information_schema.tables
                WHERE table_name LIKE '{$wp}%'`

Comment: I'm not too sure about that query... I don't know that much about MySQL (only a little more than needed to answer your question). Take a look at [SELECT with CONCAT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734570/mysql-select-with-concat-condition) for help.