# Use Entity's method in DQL (Symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony

My Symfony2 app has a `Person` entity, it has `$firstName` and `$lastName` as its properties. It's got a method `getFullName()` which returns the full name of `Person`.

```
// Vendor/Bundle/Entity/Person.php
public function getFullName()
{
    return $this->firstName . ' ' . $this->lastName;
}
```

Now, I want to allow users to search `Person`. There is only one search field which users can enter some value. The value can be the full name, first name, or last name of the person they look for.

Here is some code from controller which will do the filtering:

```
// Vendor/Bundle/Controller/PersonController.php
public function listAction(Request $request)
{
    // ...
    $people = $this->get('doctrine')
        ->getRepository('SomeBundle:Person')
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('p.fullName = :fullName')
        ->setParameter('fullName', $request->query->get('fullName'))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    // ...
}
```

However, it doesn't work. Apparently, it is because `fullName` is not one of `Person`'s fields.

Is there a way to filter results using QueryBuilder, i.e. I do not want to iterate over all results and compare their names?

---

Although [Victor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22066427/1762803) shows the correct result, I am still looking for a more 'elegant' way to do this. Please post your suggestion as answer if you have one!

Comment: Well, it is because fullName is not a Person's field. Either you store it, or you filter on firstName or/and lastName (in your where clause).

Comment: @Brice But it won't work if a user enter the full name of a person.

Comment: Why not? Just `explode()` the fullName and compare each part with `firstName` and `lastName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about to explode `fullName` with space:

```
// Vendor/Bundle/Controller/PersonController.php
public function listAction(Request $request)
{
    // ...
    $name = explode(' ', $request->query->get('fullName'));
    $people = $this->get('doctrine')
        ->getRepository('SomeBundle:Person')
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('p.firstname = :firstName')
        ->andWhere('p.lastName = :lastName')
        ->setParameter('firstName', $name[0])
        ->setParameter('lastName', $name[1])
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    // ...
}
```

or try to concatenate `firstName` and `lastName` fields in query:

```
// Vendor/Bundle/Controller/PersonController.php
public function listAction(Request $request)
{
    // ...
    $people = $this->get('doctrine')
        ->getRepository('SomeBundle:Person')
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('CONCAT(p.firstName, ' ', p.lastName) = :fullName')
        ->setParameter('fullName', $request->query->get('fullName'))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    // ...
}
```

**NOTE:**
it may be inaccurate if you change `getFullName()` behaviour

Comment: No, what about a guy called *"Hey my name is"* ?

Comment: What if `name = lastName + firstName` ?

Comment: @Touki You need to use two text fields in form and get `firstName` and `lastName` separately

Comment: Yes, that's it, I was writing my answer but you were too fast. Please, add a note that says that it may be inaccurate if you change `getFullname` behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! I've found something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734570/mysql-select-with-concat-condition)!