# How do i concat two columns in Database and then select all values against it

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code but on clicking `Login` button it shows error like this

> Connection MaintainedError: select * from signup where username='abc' and password='1234'

```
if(isset($_POST['log'])){
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$dbm = new MySQLi("localhost","root","","lsa");
    if($dbm->connect_errno > 0){
        die("Error".$dbm->connect_error);
        }
        var_dump($dbm);
        echo "Connection Maintained";
        $up = "update signup set username = concat(First_name, ' ' , Last_Name)";
        $qm="select * from signup where username='$uname' and password='$pass'";
        if ($dbm->query($qm) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $qm . "<br>" . $dbm->error;
                }   

$dbm->close();
```

> here is my login form code*

```
<form action="Admin.php" method="post">
<fieldset style="text-align:center; margin-left:2%; margin-top:9%; margin-right:10%">
<legend style="text-align:start; font-family:'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif; color:#FFF; font-size:36px">Login
</legend>
<br /><input type="text" placeholder=" Username" name="uname" title="Your First Name" style="height:25px; width:200px" required="required"  /><br /><br />
<input type="password" placeholder=" Password" name="pass" style="height:25px; width:200px" required="required" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="log" style=" border-radius:50%; border-color:#FFF; width:100px" />
<br />
<br />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Before we go any further, your code in its present form is highly susceptible to SQL Injection attacks.  Read http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Also, the use of inline styles is discouraged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL select with CONCAT condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734570/mysql-select-with-concat-condition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from php.net about the return value of `mysqli::query`:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN
>   queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful 
>   queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

So line 12 is a problem. That's prob. why you are getting an error (at least one option, check out http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

But that is not the answer to the title of the question, If you **are** trying to concat data in the database and compare the data to more data that's in the database then use a *subquery* (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html)

**Edit:**

Also, and this is only a suspicion of mine, when you echo after the fail of the query you are not getting an error code/str (`$dbm->error`) that may be because their is no error and `$dbm->error` is `NULL`

**Edit 2:**
It seems that you are not using `$up` at all in the code, am I wrong?