# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException when using PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to execute a query that returns a student whose name and last name concatenated equal the search key parameter.

For that I am doing this in my class that manages anything related to the database for my `Student` class.

When the query is executed I am getting the error that follows:

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:`

What's wrong? I have checked that's the correct [way to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734570/mysql-select-with-concat-condition) `concat`.

`name` and `lastName` are `VARCHAR` in the mysql database.

```
public static Student findStudent(String key) {
    if (key == null) return null;

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String selectSQL = "select * from project.students where concat(name, lastName) = ? ;";

    try {
      dbConnection = getDBConnection();

      preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
      preparedStatement.setString(1, key);

      Student student = null;
      rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL);
      if (rs.next()) {
          StudentDB.setStudentAttributes(student, rs);
      }

      return student;
    } catch(SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      close();
      try {
          if (preparedStatement != null) preparedStatement.close();
          if (rs != null) rs.close();
      } catch(SQLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What is the complete error message you're getting? Consider changing your catch blocks to something that will print all information available (not just print the stack trace) - for debugging rethrow it as `throw new RuntimeException(e);` to see if that yields a more specific error message.

Comment: Also, you can try deleting the trailing semicolon (not sure it will help but some JDBC drivers don't like them)

Comment: preparedStatement.executeUpdate(); ???

Comment: I agree with @PetterFriberg; that `.executeUpdate()` ain't gonna work. But also, what is the `StudentDB` reference and what is the `.setStudentAttributes` method call actually doing? I think you will have to add more detail to get help with this -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you prepare the statement with

```java
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
```

which is correct, but then when you try to execute the PreparedStatement you supply the `selectSQL` string again:

```java
rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL);
```

That is incorrect. You've already prepared the statement, so when the time comes to execute it you just do

```java
rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```