# Merge two database columns into one array column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm attempting to get a few particular columns from a table of people with a catch: I would like to concatenate the first two columns together.

More specifically, I have the following array:

```
@people=@company.people.select(fname, lname, email, telephone, street, city, state, zip,)
```

I would like, however to concatenate fname and lname together into one column (call it name) so they appear like this:

```
{lname}, {fname}
```

I suppose I could do this using a loop with an index but is there a more elegant solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the database to help you with this. For example, if you're using Postgres, you can do something like

```
@people = @company.people.select("fname || ', ' || lname as name")
```

If you're using Mysql, the answers to [MySQL select with CONCAT condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5734570/163640) can help you with the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
@company.people.select('({fname}, || ' ' || {lname} as name), email, telephone, street, city, state, zip')
```