# adding '0,' before every column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying an 0, before every column in my sql

```
select TemporaryStock * '0,'+ cast( VAT as varchar(50)) from Market
```

i get error Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to float.

Comment: '0,' is not a float value then how it will convert from varchar to float?

Comment: why is there an asterisk in your SQL?

Comment: Shoud i use 0.?

Comment: Really not clear what you are going for.  Perhaps some sample data and desired results

Comment: What is your input, what is your expected output?

Comment: my input value is 5*24 and i want to make it 5*0.24

Comment: Text needs to be displayed like that or you need the calculated value of 5*0.24?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cast... you just need to move the decimal.

```
select TemporaryStock * (VAT * 0.01) from Market
```

If you want every value to be like 0.###### then you can use:

```
select TemporaryStock  * convert(decimal(38,37),'0.' + convert(varchar,VAT))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add '0' before the VAT then use CONCAT(args1, args2) method:

select CONCAT('0',VAT) from ExpressMarket;

Note: Both the arguments should be of **string** type.

Or else you can refer the following to know more about how to concatenate and aliasing it.

[MySQL select with CONCAT condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734570/mysql-select-with-concat-condition)

Comment: OP has SQL Server 2008 tagged not MySQL. `CONCAT()` in SQL Server is only for 2012 onward

Comment: I need it for sql server