# Query in MySQL and SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a problem to a help of every people:
In Mysql, my query:

```
select * from readquestion where readexerciseid= "+readexerciseid+" limit "+(start-1)+", "+count+";
```

I want to ask with this query in SQL Server, how should I do this?

Comment: Did you try CONCAT() ? if yes please paste the query and error you are getting. For reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734570/mysql-select-with-concat-condition

Answer (score 0):

In [SQLServer](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) use 'top' keyword to limit the results.
The SELECT TOP clause is used to specify the number of records to return.

The SELECT TOP clause is useful on large tables with thousands of records. Returning a large number of records can impact on performance.
Sytax:

```
SELECT TOP number|percent column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
```

Eg:

```
int count = start - 1 + count; //calculate limit here
"select top "+ count +" * from readquestion where readexerciseid= "+readexerciseid
```

Note: Not all database systems support the SELECT TOP clause. MySQL supports the LIMIT clause to select a limited number of records, while Oracle uses ROWNUM.
In mysql use 'limit' keyword to limit the results.

syntax:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
LIMIT number;
```

E.g.:

```
int count = start - 1 + count; //calculate limit here
"select * from readquestion where readexerciseid= "+readexerciseid+" limit "+ count
```