# How to combine CONCAT() and WHERE in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I like to use the result from another query to address the column name. For this I like to use `CONCAT()`. But somehow it don't work; when I run this line I get 0 rows back:

`SELECT * FROM cover WHERE CONCAT('c','9') = 1;`

When I don't make use of `CONCAT()` it work perfectly:

`SELECT * FROM cover WHERE c9 = 1;`

And also `CONCAT()` seems to work. With this I get a result:

`SELECT CONCAT('c','9');`

I tried all solution from this question:
[MySQL select with CONCAT condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734570/mysql-select-with-concat-condition)

like this one, but i always got 0rows back:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, CONCAT('c', '9') as target 
  FROM cover) base 
WHERE target = "1"
```

My MySQL Version is; 10.1.16-MariaDB

Comment: `concat` produces a string, which is not interpreted as the name of a column. If you could use a program (eg php, perl, python) to build the column name dynamically, that'd be easier.

Comment: @ringø thanks, i will consider to do it in php. but in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734570/mysql-select-with-concat-condition it look like that it is possible.

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation...i will go with php ;) ...and yes, I want to make a column name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is bad schema design to splay an array across a bunch of columns.  And, as you are discovering, it is hard to use the columns.  Build another table for the `c` values.

Or...

With lots of 0/1 "columns", consider `SET` or `BIGINT UNSIGNED`; either will hold up to 64 boolean flags in a tiny fraction of the space.  And, with different code, `BLOB` could be used.

To extract bit 22 from a `BIGINT`, `((col >> 22) & 1)` will give you 0 or 1.

Comment: Interesting. The table i like to design have about 100k rows and between 100 and 1000 columns. I have to fill every field with a 1 or 0. For me this looks like a perfect case for use a matrix. You tell me it is more efficient to create a table with 3 columns (the both dimensions and the value) which is between 10M and 1000M rows long??

Comment: I augmented my answer.  Could you provide more details on how the data will be used?  Are you looking for c9 to "filter" or to "compute" or what?

Comment: Thanks so far...I think it is better when i open a new question, because this one seems not a good place to discus this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a `case when`, since the number of options is known beforehand (you can only access columns that exist):

```
SELECT id 
FROM   cover 
WHERE  case ? 
           when 1 then c1
           when 2 then c2
           when 9 then c9
       end = 1
```

... where the question mark would be the provided value, like 9 in your example.